# Send another variable using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

This is my code

```
 $(function () {
              
               
                $("#txtUserName").autocomplete({
                   
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                           

                            url: '/Home/UserNameAutoComplete',
                            data: 
                               
                                "{ 'username': '" + request.term + "'}",
```

- I want to send another variable txtLastName.val()

i tried doing this

```
 data: { term: request.term, agency:$('#txtLastName').val())}
```

But its giving me an error:

```
<title>Invalid JSON primitive: term.</title>
```

Comment: have you tried by using: `data: {username: request.term}` ... well given `console.log(request.term)` gives you in console something valid. Otherwise your question is hard to debug as it stands currently.

Comment: @Roko that one is valid, It's giving me right value, what I wanted to know is how to add another value, The right syntax to add the value of txtLastName.val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you reported is due to a typo:

```
data: { term: request.tem, agency:$('#txtLastName').val())}
```

You will see that `request.tem` does not exists. You want to call `request.term`.

Assuming your script can accept it, you can do the following.

```
$(function () {
  $("#txtUserName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UserNameAutoComplete',
        data: {
          username: request.term,
          agency: $('#txtLastName').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
          response(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I notice in your example, you're sending a text string: `"{ 'username': '" + request.term + "'}"` which is a little strange. If that is truely what you need to send, it would be something like:

```
data: "{ 'username': '" + request.term + "', 'agency': '" + $('#txtLastName').val() + "'}"
```

I suggest testing my first solution.

Comment: Sir, this one worked for me as i needed to pass a string. data: "{ 'username': '" + request.term + "', 'agency': '" + $('#txtLastName').val() + "'}" ..Thank you